# ClassNotFoundException: Running JUnit Tests in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit, classnotfoundexception

I have a project with src, classes & tests. I keep my JUnit tests in the tests folder.
I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException while running them in Eclipse.
I tried running them using from the Command line.

```
        javac -d classes src\brick\*.java test\brick\*.java
```

The compiler reports 20 errors telling me that the package org.junit does not exist.
Could anybody help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to manage your dependencies (maven, contained in a lib dir)? Are all of the necessary jars in your classpath?

Comment: Yes the JUnit jar is in the classpath.

Comment: But I while running through Eclipse I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException for not only for the tests but also for the ordinary classes

Comment: Can you provide more information on your directory structure and build configuration in eclipse?

Comment: Maybe look over this tutorial a bit, it might give you some ideas of what setup options you might be missing

http://www.vogella.de/articles/JUnit/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Javac needs to know where your JUnit jar is located in order to compile your classes.
You should try something like:

```
javac -cp <path to junit jar> -d classes src\brick\*.java test\brick\*.java
```

When in Eclipse, you need to add the JUnit jar to your project. Normally this is
done automatically if you have a test case...

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. After compiling it, I tried running it with java -cp classes test\brick.BrickTest but I got a NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: I am currently using Eclipse but it keeps giving me a ClassNotFoundException for the classes a their tests

Comment: Eclipse may have a problem compiling your classes because of errors. Does your Eclipse build automatically? Check Window -> Preferences -> Workspace -> Build automatically.

Comment: No, there aren't any errors. I use Eclipse Indigo & the build automatically option isn't there where you mentioned.

Comment: Anyway ClassNotFoundException happens at runtime

Comment: Uhm, weirdness. I have also Indigo, but for Linux. Should not differ I might guess. Have you tried, just like when compiling, adding the JUnit jar to your classpath?